# How to remove the duplicate records in select query over clause

Tags: sql-server, over-clause

I am having Transactions table as follows in SQL SERVER.

```
 UserID       TranDate     Amount
    1   |   2015-04-01   |  0
    1   |   2015-05-02   |  5000
    1   |   2015-09-07   |  1000
    1   |   2015-10-01   |  -4000
    1   |   2015-10-02   |  -700
    1   |   2015-10-03   |  252
    1   |   2015-10-03   |  260
    1   |   2015-10-04   |  1545
    1   |   2015-10-05   |  1445
    1   |   2015-10-06   |  -2000
```

I want to query this table to get available balance at any particular date. So I used Windowing function for that.

```
SELECT TransactionDate, 
    SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY TransactionDate ROWS 
BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) FROM Transactions
```

But as transactions table is having duplicate entry for date 2015-10-03 it is repeating data for date 2015-10-03. Whenever there is same date I am expecting the last record of that date with available balance summed up.

**Current output**

```
TransactionDate     AvailableBalance
   2015-04-01      |       0
   2015-05-02      |       5000
   2015-09-07      |       6000
   2015-10-01      |       2000
   2015-10-02      |       1300
   2015-10-03      |       1552
   2015-10-03      |       1804
   2015-10-04      |       3349
   2015-10-05      |       4794
   2015-10-06      |       2794
```

**Expected**: I want to remove below record from the above result set.

```
   2015-10-03      |       1552
```

[HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1508e/1) is my sql fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `SUM` before windowed function like:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1508e/3/0)**

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT TransactionDate, UserId, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
  FROM Transactions
  GROUP BY TransactionDate, UserId
)
SELECT TransactionDate,  
        SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY TransactionDate ROWS 
    BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS AvailableBalance 
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `RANGE` instead of `ROWS`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1508e9/3/0)

```
SELECT
  TransactionDate,  
  SUM(Amount) OVER (
    PARTITION BY UserId 
    ORDER BY TransactionDate 
    RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS AvailableBalance
FROM Transactions;
```

This variant produces a different result set than originally requested, but it may be useful in some cases. This variant returns same number of rows as in `Transactions` table. So, it will return two rows with `2015-10-03`, but for both rows `AvailableBalance` would be `1804`.

I just wanted to highlight that there is that option `RANGE`. If you really need one row per day, then grouping by day at first as in the answer by @lad2025 is the way to go.

Comment: OP will have to add `DISTINCT`. Two duplicate keys are brought back `2015-10-03 1804`

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas, yes, you are right. This variant produces a different result set than originally requested, but it may be useful in some cases. I just wanted to highlight that there is that option `RANGE`. If you really need one row per day, then grouping by day at first as in the answer by @lad2025 is the way to go.

Comment: Not arguing. It's indeed a very useful tip.